# Equivalent of and in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What's the equivalent of and in JS because I can't seem to find an answer

```
}else if (i % 3 & 5 === 0){
console.log('...')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A googling for "javascript AND operator" returns a first hit of http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp which clearly explains the answer:

```
if (i % 3 && 5 === 0)
```

This is the answer you're looking for, but given how it's written, it might not give you the outcome you expect depending on execution.

Comment: I have tried && but it does not work for some strange reason

Comment: && is the AND operator, the thing you are asking about. As I said, it may not work as you expect given that you're not using parenthesis to indicate how you expect this to be processes. Right now, it doesn't look like what you've indicated would actually run - what you're saying is get the remainder of i divided by 3 and then AND that to 5 (which would be an illegal operation). What are you even attempt to calculate?

Comment: Oh, you're doing FizzBuzz... just google the dang answer.

Comment: @JonHartmann Look at this code
http://pastebin.com/Ka6TkmcA

So if it divides by 3 and 5 it logs the following

Comment: This appears incorrect.  The original code does a bitwise AND whereas this code does a logical AND.  The results are not the same. In binary, 010 && 101 === 0 is false whereas 010 & 101 === 0 is true. And if one were using the code to test bit flags then this would return the wrong result.